# What is the correct notation for equations and sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

If i want to continue this equation, which logic connective is the most correct or most people use in tests:

$$ 2x = 4   \rightarrow x= 2       $$ or $$2x =4\Rightarrow x=2    $$ or $$2x=4    \leftrightarrow x=2$$ or $$2x=4\Leftrightarrow x=2$$
or $$2x=4 \equiv x=2  $$

In elementary set theory, i saw many books with this notation:

$$A\subset B\leftrightarrow \forall x\in A\rightarrow x\in B $$ but in this case, if the right-hand side of iff is wrong, all the sentence will be, because we consider the left-hand side as a correct statement. But, with this notation, it will never ocur:

$$A\subset B \equiv \forall x\in A \Rightarrow x\in B$$

Because the right-hand side of iff will always be correct.

Comment: I suggest that when discussing the left and right sides of expressions, and the rightness and wrongness of statements, you use some term other than "right" for both.  I personally would go with "right-hand side" instead of "right side" and "correct statement" instead of "right statement".

Comment: You are correct, i will change it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convention is that the single arrow "$ \rightarrow $" is used as a logical operator *in the formal language*: $P \rightarrow Q$ is a formula (pronounced "if P then Q") which is defined to be true when $Q$ is true or $P$ is false.

The double arrow "$\Rightarrow$" is conventionally used *outside* the formal language, as a shorthand for "implies" (or "this means" or "and hence") in the (English) conversation that the writer is having with the reader. So if you're doing a sequence of calculations as part of a proof or exam answer, $\Rightarrow$ is the one you want between each equation.

The two-headed arrows observe the same convention. So "$\leftrightarrow$" is a logical connective, and the formula $P \leftrightarrow Q$ is true if $P$ and $Q$ are both true or both false. You can also write this "$\equiv$".

Thus your set-theory text is using the correct arrows: 
$$A\subset B\leftrightarrow \forall x (x\in A\rightarrow x\in B) $$
is a formula in the language of set theory which defines the symbol $\subset$: since that formula is true, wherever you see $A \subset B$ you can substitute $\forall x (x\in A\rightarrow x\in B)$. (Your alternative notation breaks convention, but if we changed the conventions so that it was O.K, your problems with interpretation would not go away. The new symbols would have the same meaning as the old ones did.)

The dangerous symbol is "$\Leftrightarrow$", which means "implies, and is implied by" or "or equivalently" (or even "if and only if") -- if you use it, it's a claim that you can read your argument up the page as well as down it. There are very few contexts where this is helpful, because most arguments need extra conditions or assumptions somewhere along the way, and using $\Leftrightarrow$ is a standing temptation not to check every stage of the reverse argument. It's much better to write it out twice.

In short, if you need to prove that $P \leftrightarrow Q$, then assume $P$, work until you have proved $Q$ writing $\Rightarrow$ between the lines where appropriate; then assume $Q$ and work (again with $\Rightarrow$s) to prove $P$. And give yourself a big Q.E.D.

Comment: I don’t agree with the penultimate paragraph. If you must use symbols instead of words, $\Leftrightarrow$ is perfectly fine; you merely have to use it correctly, but that’s true of any notation. There is no reason to write something out twice if it genuinely can be written just once.

Comment: Actually, in the language of set theory $\subseteq$ is not a formal symbol, but rather a shorthand for a formula. So $\iff$ fits slightly better. Note that $\p\implies q$ is true if and only if $p\rightarrow q$ is a tautology; so in the context of classical logic, it doesn't *really* matter which one you use as long as you are aware of their differences.

Answer (score 4):

The first four are all correct; I definitely would not use the fifth, as $\equiv$ has too many other uses. However, I don’t really recommend that you use any of them: plain English (or whatever language) is preferable. If what’s important to the argument is that you can derive $x=2$ from $2x=4$, then just say something like this:

> $2x=4$, so $x=4$.

If what’s important is that the two statements are equivalent, and you’re using that fact to justify some assertion $P$, then say something like this:

> $2x=4$ if and only if $x=2$, so $P$.

Comment: Thank you very much, Brian. But, what if i have bigger equations?

Comment: @Voyager: You’re very welcome. Do you mean making the same sorts of statements about more complicated expressions? My advice would be exactly the same.

Comment: I respectfully disagree: especially in the context of set theory, where the formal language is important, $\rightarrow$ is not available as a shorthand for English "implies". The first and second options mean different things.

Comment: @HTFB: In everyday informal mathematical writing of the kind pretty clearly under discussion here they are largely interchangeable (and I don’t recommend using either). That’s true of much mathematical writing even in set-theoretic contexts.

Comment: It seems as though the questioner is reading texts in which the formal implication $\rightarrow$ appears, and misunderstanding the relationship between formulae of the set-theoretic language and sentences of English. In the formal language you could deprecate $P \rightarrow Q$ in favour of $\neg P \vee Q$  but that is no gain in clarity. The English conjunction $\Rightarrow$ doesn't appear in papers but is inevitable on blackboards or exam scripts; it is at least better than $\therefore$. And I've never seen a set theorist or model theorist (or any practicing mathematician!) confuse the two.

Comment: @HTFB: I don’t confuse them; I simply don’t use $\Rightarrow$ at all except to accommodate someone else. I use $\to$ as the informal symbol on the extremely rare occasions when I don’t use English. And I think that your answer misses the most important point and is in part factually incorrect.

Comment: I'm surprised. Since $\rightarrow$ is already hopelessly overloaded with meanings of convergence, or the relationship between domain and codomain of a function, etc, it's the last symbol I'd want cropping up between lines of my working, or a student's, however informal.

Answer (score 1):

My intuition as to some symbols is as follows:

$\rightarrow$ is a directional with the connotation "goes to."  So I might write $f(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$.

$\Rightarrow$ is an inference which I would say out loud as "implies."  An example would be $ABC$ is a right triangle with right angle at $B\Rightarrow |AB|^2+|BC|^2=|AC|^2$.

$↔$ is not a symbol I've seen used very often, but it suggests a bidirectional "goes to" meaning, which doesn't make sense to me.

$\iff$ is clearly "if and only if" and is the same to me as $⇔$, although the longer arrow is sometimes preferred (by me anyways) to help add readability spacing to a statement.

$\equiv$ is an equivalence relation, like congruence under a modulus.  I have seen it used to mean "is defined as," but that actually added a bit of confusion to what was being said.

Just a note on the right hand side of the example you use at the end:

$$\forall x\in A\Rightarrow x\in B$$

In English, I read this as "for all $x$ in $A$ implies $x$ in $B$."  This doesn't sound right to me, so I would prefer to write the statement as

$$\forall x\in A, x\in B$$

or more directly

$$x\in A\implies x\in B$$

Comment: Both $\leftarrow,\rightarrow$ and $\leftrightarrow$ are connective in propositional calculus (and first-order logic); which is the correct context of this question. Saying that $x\to\infty$ is the connotation you have may be correct, but it is not correct for this context.

Comment: I appreciate that context does have importance as to symbol meaning.  I'm just attempting to offer what I think are the "usual interpretation" of the difference between $\leftarrow$ vs. $\Leftarrow$ and $\rightarrow$ vs. $\Rightarrow$...

Comment: But $\rightarrow$ *has* a usual interpretation in logic, and it's not "goes to".

Comment: So if $\rightarrow$ has a specific meaning in logic, how is that meaning different from $\Rightarrow$?

Comment: $\varphi\rightarrow\psi$ is a proposition, the $\rightarrow$ is a symbol in the formal language of propositional calculus. On the other hand, $\varphi\implies\psi$ is a statement *about* propositions, it's not a proposition. So $\implies$ is a symbol in the *meta-language* of propositional calculus. The two symbols have a very deep connection, but they have different meanings.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, now I will consider how and whether I should modify my answer...

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution set to any statement form. We'll denote by “$A(.)\iff B(.)$” that $A(.)$ and $B(.)$ have the same solution set.  In your case: “The double of a number equals $4$” $\iff$ “A number equals $2$.”